# Call function inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

```js
let f = function(x) {
  alert(x)
}

(function() {
  f(1)
}())
```

Why is this code throwing an error? At first, I thought the problem was connected with the incorrect syntax of the IIFE but then I learned that this syntax is also appropriate

Comment: What error is it showing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the one of the rare cases where a semicolon is necessary to separate the function expression from the calling with the following parentheses.

```js
let f = function(x) {
  alert(x)
}; // <-------------------

(function() {
  f(1)
}())
```